# A post var error upon webform submitting programmatically

Tags: 7, webforms

I need to update a webform submission using function drupal_form_submit.

And upon updating an error is displayed.

> This form could not be submitted because $_POST was truncated to 5
>   input vars. PHP max_input_vars is 10000 and needs to be increased

I tried to increase max_input_vars value even up to billion, but it doesn't helps.

The webform is very big and complicated.

Here I can't use function webform_submission_update, because some form alter and form validation functions must be executed upon the webform submission updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2677936

If it's a custom webform template, you may need to add, at the end of the form:

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

See also this related issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2417757